# How to create nested folders in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, document-library

I have a scenario of creating a kind of DMS using libraries. The scenario is i have to have multiple levels of folders of libraries based upon some category. e.g.

```
HR
 Training of Staff
     Internal Training
     External Training
```

I tried to use metadata navigation for the purpose but it does not provide me the level of hierarchy shown above.
My question is if it is possible in SharePoint 2013 without customization or coding.

Cheers
Raheel